# How to show a report that has "numbers in thousands" as full numbers?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

If I have a lot of numbers in thousands and I don't want to use regexp to append to them three zeros to see the real number how can I proceed? I didn't found yet a formatting solution or any other solution.

The data sets are companies Balance Sheets like this:
[image]

Here is an editable example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sU8k0YBZc4IJc0qMl3qRkLc5E2rOAZ2E18i-xtxqt5I/edit?usp=sharing

What I found is in Excel:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3524-excel-add-trailing-zeros-to-number.html

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Comment: I added an editable example to my question

Comment: You said _I added my sample I see that is more accurate whats is my issue_.  I'm sorry, I don't see that "your issue" is any more accurate than previously. The only difference that I can see between the answer by @doubleunary and others compared to your spreadsheet is that on your "Solution" sheet the cell content is not formula-driven but actual values. Of course, you could achieve this by using either answer, then accessing the menu "Copy > Paste special > Values only".  If you have a more specific issue than this, then you need to edit your question and describe the issue in more detail.

Comment: @Tedinoz in my first question version wasn't added image & spreadsheet sample. So after that, I added them I hope was more accurate what is my issue. The Solution sheet was created by doubleunary. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the report in full numbers, **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of a new sheet:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    isnumber(Sheet1!A1:Z) * (row(Sheet1!A1:Z) > 2), 
    1000 * Sheet1!A1:Z, 
    Sheet1!A1:Z 
  ) 
)
```

The formula fills the whole sheet automatically, multiplying every number below row 2 by one thousand, and returning other values as is.

To show the multiplied numbers in the same sheet in another column, use this formula in row 2 of a free column:

`=arrayformula(A2:A * 1000)`

To show the original value on rows where there is no number, use `iferror()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( 1 / A2:A * 1000 ^ -1, A2:A ) )`

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sU8k0YBZc4IJc0qMl3qRkLc5E2rOAZ2E18i-xtxqt5I/edit#gid=480536021).

Comment: I have companies Balance Sheets like this: https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/tsla/financials  (with more than 10 years - I added an image to my question also). In this case, is still easier to copy all the data in a notped++ and solve it by regexp, than use the formula that you suggested - that is perfect for one column of data as I understood. Thank you for your response

Comment: @ArnoldVakaria Please don't be dismissive of this answer - it is sound AND adjusts to multiple columns. `=arrayformula(A2:A * 1000)` is easily edited to `=arrayformula(A2:B * 1000)` (which processes numbers in both Column A **AND** Column B). Also, if you have raw data on, say, "Sheet1" then the formula can be edited to create "updated" values on, say, "Sheet 2" - that is, raw data is intact but you have a "view" that is dynamically updated.  Also, please recognise that you are providing more information than was in your original question; the author may well have a solution to your revision.

Comment: @Tedinoz I didn't want to be dismissive I just want to summarize what and how I understood. My understanding wasn't complete as you already reflected that I could use the array formula also for the sheets - thanks for the idea. Sure, I also recognized that I added more info (image, example sheet) - it's visible in my answer comment. After that I got the response I upvoted the answer, but because I don't have enough reputation it doesn't have any effect. Naturally, I will wait until doubleunary will get the sample suggested and when I will get the simplest solution I will accept that

Comment: No worries. As the author of the question, you may not be able to upvote but if a particular answer is helpful then you can accept it.

Comment: Thank you @doubleunary, I like the solution that you made in my sample file. I accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

This answer is offered simply to show that there are many ways of answering this question. This is no better nor worse that the answer by @doubleunary.

- Let's assume the data is on "Sheet1"
- Create a new "Sheet2"
- Enter this formula in Cell A1 of Sheet2

`=query({Sheet1!A1:A5,Sheet1!C1:D5},"select Col1, Col2*1000, Col3*1000 where Col1 is not null label Col2*1000 '', Col3*1000 '' format Col2*1000 '#,###',Col3*1000 '#,###'",2)`

---

**Sheet1**

[image: sheet1]

**Sheet2**

[image: sheet2]

---

Obviously this example is hand-written based on a small number of columns, but this can be expanded to dynamically reference many columns by adapting   [Google Sheets Query sum indeterminate number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58846200/1330560) from StackOverflow (and for which there are several examples in WebApps).

Comment: Thank you for your response. After that, I added my sample I see that is more accurate whats is my issue and I'm getting more specific answers

Comment: I added my sample to see more accurate whats is my issue - I want to write something like this